# Twitter Hashtags rss feed

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, rss, hashtag

I've been searching around the internet for an working twitter hashtag rss feed. But they were all outdates / not working.
Example, echo'ing all the tweets with an "#EK2012" .
I would apprentice if someone could help me.

(Its for on my new website)

Greetings.

Comment: Can't you just use the twitter API? It is made for this purpose?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go: 
http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=%23EK2012